Centering things vertically in a memoir footer?
I have a feeling this should be very simple, but I can't get it to work for some reason. Here's what I have so far:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{showframe} %enable to see frames
\makepagestyle{gjc-letterhead}
\makeoddfoot{gjc-letterhead}{%
\begin{minipage}[c][3cm][t]{0.33\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=29.9mm]{example-image-a}%
\end{minipage}}%
{%
\begin{minipage}[c][3cm][t]{0.33\textwidth}%
\vfill\null
foo\\
bar\\
bat\\
boo
\vfill\null
\end{minipage}}
{%
\begin{minipage}[c][3cm][c]{0.33\textwidth}%
\vfill\null
bar
\vfill\null
\end{minipage}}
\makeevenhead{gjc-letterhead}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{gjc-letterhead}{}{}{}
\setlength{\footskip}{46pt}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{gjc-letterhead}
foo
\end{document}

What to do?

Without \vfill a simple \begin{minipage}[3cm]{0.33\textwidth}% centered by default

It's unclear what you want, but perhaps this is what you need, namely to remove the [t] bit.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe} %enable to see frames

\newcommand{\footerelement}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}[c][3cm]{0.33\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
}

\makepagestyle{gjc-letterhead}
\makeoddfoot{gjc-letterhead}{%
  \footerelement{\includegraphics[width=29.9mm]{example-image-a}}\hfil
  \footerelement{%
    foo\\
    bar\\
    bat\\
    boo
  }\hfil
  \footerelement{bar}
}{}{}
\makeevenhead{gjc-letterhead}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{gjc-letterhead}{}{}{}
\setlength{\footskip}{46pt}

\checkandfixthelayout

\pagestyle{gjc-letterhead}

\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}



Have a look at some documentation e.g. minipage on LaTeX2e: An unofficial reference manual.
I am not very familiar with memoir document class but it seems to me you probably should make some space for this footer. Below is the code of yours but slightly altered.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[
    pass,
    showframe,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makepagestyle{gjc-letterhead}
\makeoddfoot{gjc-letterhead}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b][][t]{\linewidth}
        \begin{minipage}{29.9mm}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
            foo\\bar\\bat\\boo
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
            bar
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{minipage}}{}{}
\makeevenhead{gjc-letterhead}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{gjc-letterhead}{}{}{}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{5\onelineskip}% \setlength{\footskip}{46pt}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{gjc-letterhead}
foo
\clearpage
bar
\end{document}


